# How to write concurrent unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, concurrency

[Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) is a great tool to unit-test concurrent production code.

Question: Is there a tool to ease writing concurrent test code?

Suppose I wanted to test `java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue`.

```
public class BlockingQueueTest {
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> out;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        out = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    }

    @Test
    public void putThenGet() throws InterruptedException {
        // that's easy because it can be done in one thread
        out.put("Hello");

        String taken = out.take();

        assertThat(taken).isEqualTo("Hello");
    }

    @Test
    public void getBeforePut() throws InterruptedException {
        // that's more tricky because it can't be done with one thread
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            out.put("Hello");
            return null;
        });
        executorService.shutdown();

        String taken = out.take();

        assertThat(taken).isEqualTo("Hello");
    }
}
```

`getBeforePut()` is no fun to code. Is there a way to make it less hard and more readable, like so?

```
@Test
public void getBeforePut2() throws InterruptedException {
    // Wanted: DSL for concurrent test-code
    Concurrently.sleep(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).andThen(() -> out.put("Hello"));

    String taken = out.take();

    assertThat(taken).isEqualTo("Hello");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just implement that `Concurrently` class yourself? You already have the code that it is supposed to execute, it's now just a matter of refactoring. And the result will have about 30 lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Using [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) is the easiest way as for me:

```
 @Test(threadPoolSize = 10, invocationCount = 15, timeOut = 1000)
 public void testPut(){
     out.put("Hello");
 }
```

This test will run 15 times in 10 threads and should take no longer than 1000 ms.

Also you can create tests which depends on other test

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = "testPut")
public void testGetAfterPut{
    String taken = out.take();

    assertThat(taken).isEqualTo("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(A) you can just use Thread without the need of an ExecutorService

```
@Test
public void getBeforePutWithThread() throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        out.put("Hello");
    }).run();

    String taken = out.take();

    assertThat(taken).isEqualTo("Hello");
}
```

(B) You can take this all functionality to a simple function and avoid dependency on external lib

```
private void runWithDelay(long delay, Runnable action) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            action.run();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).run();     
}

@Test
public void getBeforePutWithFunction() {
    runWithDelay(100, () -> out.put("Hello"));

    String taken = out.take();

    assertThat(taken).isEqualTo("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By now I'm writing all my tests in kotlin. And with kotlin testing this is easy peasy and fun!

Worth mentioning when testing with threads is [JUnit's @Timeout Annotation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Timeout.html), which prevents false tests from running infinitely.

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Timeout
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
import kotlin.concurrent.thread

class BlockingQueueKotlinTests {
    // objectUnderTest
    private val out = LinkedBlockingQueue<String>()

    @Test
    fun `put then get`() {
        // that's easy because it can be done in one thread
        out.put("Hello")

        val taken = out.take()

        assertThat(taken).isEqualTo("Hello")
    }

    @Test
    @Timeout(1)
    fun `get before put`() {
        // thanks to kotlin it's really easy to do that in another thread
        thread {
            Thread.sleep(100)
            out.put("kotlin is great!")
        }

        val taken = out.take()

        assertThat(taken).isEqualTo("kotlin is great!")
    }
}
```